# Strategy to omit unused boost src files while shipping source code

Tags: c++, c++11, matrix, boost

I'm using

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
```

in fact that's the only boost file I've included. Now I want to ship the source code and I was hoping not have to include all hundreds of MBs of `boost_1_67_0`.

How to deal with this issue?

Comment: Header files may need other header files included by them. There's no guarantee that the header files of a header only library are all self contained.

Comment: Ship only your source, with a well-documented dependency on Boost ublas. Then the users of your source, if they want to build it, need to install Boost themselves. That's the usual way to handle public library dependencies in the open-source world.

Comment: If I publish source code that makes use of boost, I just list boost as development environment precondition for it, and leave it to the behalf of the consumer to get a copy of the latest boost version themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply something you would add to the list of build-dependencies of your C++ source code.

This kind of dependency could be made technically "bound" to your source code distribution via your version control system. In [Git](https://git-scm.com/), for example, you could link to certain Boost libraries via a sub-module that links to their official git mirrors ([github.com/boostorg](https://github.com/boostorg) as of this writing). When cloning your repository, it would then be an option to take in the Boost libraries at the same time.

Though, taking the size of the Boost headers into consideration, having them installed as a system-wide library, might be less complicated. Tools like [CMake](https://cmake.org/overview/) can help you write the logic for header-inclusion so you can support different header locations.

Of course, if what you seek is to create a fully isolated copy of your source code, the approach to bake all code into one massive header-file might be an option as well (but it should not be necessary).

Comment: May I ask some more words about the CMake approach, where and what should I look for?

Comment: @KcFnMi CMake is a tool with its own scripting language (the [CMake language](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html)). It is used as a "metacompiler"; a tool that can generate the necessary makefiles for your compiler toolchain. This makes it possible to support many kinds of toolchains, be it GCC, Clang, or Microsoft Visual Studio. If you're new to CMake, it will require a bit of time and effort to learn about it (it's yet another language). Luckily, the documentation for it is well-written and everything that is required is time and reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can preprocess the one header file you need, which will expand all its #includes:

```
c++ -E /usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp -o boost_numeric_ublas_matrix.hpp
```

Be aware though: this will expand even your system header files, so it assumes your users will build on the same platform.  If they might compile on different platforms, you should simply omit the Boost code from your project and let the users install it themselves in whatever manner they choose.